# Cmake undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5 even though I link with -ldl

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, shared-libraries

I'm getting undefined reference to `dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5` even after linking it before and after the libraries. However in the linking output it appears that it's linking just before, but linking before all libraries should work, I guess.

```
/bin/g++-9     CMakeFiles/http_downloader.dir/http_downloader_cli.cpp.o CMakeFiles/http_downloader.dir/SimpleOpenVPNSocket.cpp.o  -o http_downloader  -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so -ldl downloader/libhttp_downloader_cli.a downloader/libhttp_downloader_lib.a ../../libopenvpn/libopenvpn_lib.a ../../_smoltcp_cpp_interface/libsmoltcp_cpp.a ../../_libtins/lib/libtins.a -ldl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so ../../../../smoltcp_cpp_interface/target/debug/libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so 
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../../smoltcp_cpp_interface/target/debug/libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a(std-6640d3868fa846e8.std.1mk5kra7-cgu.0.rcgu.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/examples/http_downloader/CMakeFiles/http_downloader.dir/build.make:113: src/examples/http_downloader/http_downloader] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:519: src/examples/http_downloader/CMakeFiles/http_downloader.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/build'
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

This is how I'm linking it in CMake:

```
add_executable(http_downloader http_downloader_cli.cpp SimpleOpenVPNSocket.cpp)
add_core_dependencies(http_downloader)

target_include_directories(http_downloader PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/downloader/include)
add_dependencies(http_downloader http_downloader_cli http_downloader_lib openvpn_lib smoltcp_cpp tins)
set_property(TARGET http_downloader PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries(http_downloader dl http_downloader_cli http_downloader_lib openvpn_lib smoltcp_cpp tins dl)
```

As you can see I've put `dl` before and after everything just to make sure.

If I understand correctly, `.a` libs do not have dependencies, they only have missing symbols and we have to fill them. Seems like I'm doing that by linking with `-ldl`

Comment: are all of the code and all off the libraries compiled on the same platform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would you inspect carefully the **actual command line** used for linking, you will find that **after** `libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a`, which has missed symbol, there is **no** `-ldl` parameter.

It seems that in your case `smoltcp_cpp` is an IMPORTED library **target**, which has `libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a` as a **link dependency** (not as `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property or so).

While CMake preserves order of the libraries, linked into a **single** binary (an or another library), order between **dependencies** of these libraries is not defined.

You need to add `-ldl` as a link dependency for the `smoltcp_cpp` target itself:

```
target_link_libraries(smoltcp_cpp INTERFACE -ldl)
```

---

However, this will work only if `libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a` is a **direct** link dependency for `smoltcp_cpp` target, that is specified as

```
target_link_libraries(smoltcp_cpp INTERFACE libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a)
```

In case of *indirect* dependencies, like

```
target_link_libraries(smoltcp_cpp INTERFACE <intermediate-target>)
target_link_libraries(<intermediate-target> INTERFACE libsmoltcp_cpp_interface_rust.a)
```

you need to add `-ldl` as a dependency for that `<intermediate-target>`.

Ideally, every IMPORTED target should be **self-contained**, so you may safely link with that target without knowing its internals.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make imported targets self-contained? To be fair I thought they were already like that

Comment: "how can I make imported targets self-contained?" - Just call `target_link_libraries` for that target and add those link libraries, which are required for that target. BTW, the line `target_link_libraries(smoltcp_cpp INTERFACE -ldl)` is actually a one intended to make the imported target `smoltcp_cpp` to be self-contained. "To be fair I thought they were already like that" - You link your executable - `http_downloader` - with `dl` library, but **your code** (`http_downloader_cli.cpp`, `SimpleOpenVPNSocket.cpp`) doesn't use this library. This opposites "self-contained" property of libraries.

Comment: Cmake provides a portable name for _dl_: `target_link_libraries(smoltcp_cpp INTERFACE ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})`