# Print library full-path found with target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, linker-errors

In the CMake I have:

```
target_link_libraries(${TESTNAME} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

I think libdl.so is found because the linker does not complain that: " cannot find -lld".
Still, I get the error:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test1
/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/8.3.0/real-ld: /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libport.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/8.3.0/real-ld: /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libport.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/8.3.0/real-ld: /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libport.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
```

Because I am cross-compiling, I think it might have linked the wrong file or the libdl.so might be broken.
How can I find out which file was linked by target_link_libraries? I need a full path to the file.

EDIT:
Output of `make VERBOSE=1`:

`/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++ -march=armv8-a+crc --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux --sysroot=/opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed CMakeFiles/test1.dir/test1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test1.dir/__/animateEyes.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test1.dir/__/lcd_graphics.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test1.dir/__/trajGen.cpp.o CMakeFiles/test1.dir/lcd.cpp.o  -o test1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/collar/engine -ldl /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/collar/engine/libuobject.so ../../../lib/libgtest.a ../../../lib/libgmock.a ../../../lib/libgtest_main.a /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libsched.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libserialize.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libport.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so /opt/poky/2.7.3/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.so ../../../lib/libgtest.a -lpthread`

Comment: CMake has a *built-in* variable to reference the `dl` library (see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704166/3987854)), have you tried this? Also, if you wanted to link to `libdl.so`, wouldn't you put `dl`, not `ld`?

Comment: I misspelt dl. Replacing dl with ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} does not change anything because the value of ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} is dl. It is not the question about how to link dl but how to check what actually was linked.

Comment: Information in the question post is insufficient for locate a problem. It could be that the error message and `target_link_libraries` call correspond to **different files**. Assuming your misspelled `ld` wasn't be detected by a linker, it is the very possible scenario. Please, provide [mcve].

Comment: What buildsystem are you using? With `make`, you could try `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: Running make VERBOSE=1 gives nothing more than info that g++ was run with flag: -ldl.

Comment: If there was a file created, you can run `ldd` on the built file to see a list of library dependencies and their locations.

Comment: When linker produces error, there is no built file I guess, right?

Comment: "Running make VERBOSE=1 gives nothing more than info that g++ was run with flag: -ldl" - Please, do not *describe* the error message. Instead, **show** it. E.g. that [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153342/cmake-undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlsymglibc-2-2-5-even-though-i-link-with/63154307#63154307) wouldn't be answered without the **exact error message**. By the way, that question is too about `dl` library and a missed symbol from it.

Comment: I edited question because make output has 1,5k characters - cannot post it in comment.

Comment: Still, this question is not about solving the actual problem. This question is about how to print the full path to a found library.

Comment: Have you seen the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14735544/3987854)? You may be able to include the linker trace flag `-Wl,--trace` to show the path used to link each library.